# How to write eloquent for 'and'?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, laravel-blade

I want to give a condition like `andWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $request->category . '%')`

Here is a part of the code. I want to replace 'orWhere' with equivalent and.

```
$jobs = Jobs::where('location','like', '%' . $request->location .'%')->orWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $request->category . '%')->get();
```

Comment: Just use another `where()`

Comment: Just note, if you need to mix and/or clauses, then you need to use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping)

Answer (score 3):

You can use another `where` instead of `orWhere` like this:

```php
Jobs::where('location','like', '%' . $request->location .'%')->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->category . '%')->get();
```

### Note

You can also use `dd` to confirm the query matches what you want:

```
Jobs::where('location','like', '%' . $request->location .'%')->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->category . '%')->dd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just prefer to use array instead of multiple where, 
just pass array in where() like:

```
Jobs::where([
    ['location', 'like', '%' . $request->location .'%'],
    ['category', 'like', '%' . $request->category . '%']
]);
```